# Configurable product duplicates smaller images (below the main image)

Tags: magento2.3, configurable-product

I've seen all the videos on how to configure a configurable product. And I can't find the error.[image]

See the image please.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understand I think default Magento work like it's show all images in bottom images gallery and it will update only in main image as per your selection. for example If you select red option then main image show red option image.